# Nested div not being given parent's style, using * style instead

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

I'm not understanding why the innermost nested div below isn't the same size as the `#smaller-size`. It's a direct descendant. Is it because the global `*` style is more specific? This is really gut-punching my page. What am I missing? Thanks!

```css
* { font-size: 15pt; }
#smaller-size { font-size: 0.8em; }
```

```html
<div>
    This should be the size specified by * (and it is)
    <div id="smaller-size">
        This should be the smaller size (and it is)
        <div>
            This is nested in #smaller-size, so it should also be smaller (but it's not!)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: is there any reason why you want to use the `*` selector? Why not defining the 15pt size for the body? Then all content inside `.smaller-size` will inherit the 0.8em

Comment: If it's a new project, re-think how you are defining your initial font-size. If the project is too far gone (legacy project), then try this: https://jsfiddle.net/egdsfwvL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because the global * style is more specific?

No. It is because it matches the element and `#smaller-size` does not.

Specificity only matters when both selectors match the same element.

If you didn't have `* { font-size: 15pt; }` then the inner div would have the *default* value for `font-size` which will be something along the lines of `100%` (i.e. the same size as the parent element).

You should probably just set the font size on `body` and let inheritance take case of the rest. Although there are a few gotchas:

- Form controls don't default to 100% so you might want to explicitly set the size for `input` elements and the like
- In Quirks mode fonts may not inherit into tables by default, so ensure you have a Doctype that triggers Standards mode
- `pt` is a unit designed for physical media. It does not get rendered accurately on screen. Consider using a different unit (like pixels).

Comment: Excellent explanation. I didn't fully understand the concept of default values and the idea that elements without styling directly applied simply take those values. In the case of font-size, it's useful to know the default is `100%` (I always thought it was `inherit`).

Answer (score 2):

The specificity of the "*" selector is the lowest possible (0,0,0,0), but it applies to every element applicable, so every div will be:

```
* { font-size: 15pt; }
```

By the time you are setting the new specificity with the # selector:

```
#smaller-size { font-size: 0.8em; }
```

Only the element with the corresponding id selector will have higher specificity than the rest, affected by *, which are all of them. 
Creating in this particular element (0,1,0,0) especificity value.
This id applies to that particular element only.

If for example you stablish something like:

```
#smaller-size>div { font-size: 0.2em }
```

Then all elements div under id smaller-size will have higher specificity than the ones affected by just  *

Creating something like that:

```
<div> -- specificity (0,0,0,0) = 0
  <div id="smaller-size"> -- specificity (0,1,0,0) = 100
    <div> -- specificity (0,1,0,1) = 101
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this logic:

```css
* { font-size: 15pt; }
#smaller-size { font-size: 0.8em; }
#smaller-size>div { font-size: 0.7em; }
#smaller-size>.smaller { font-size: 0.6em; }
```

```html
<div>
    specificity of this element (0,0,0,0) = 0
    <div id="smaller-size">
        specificity of this element (0,1,0,0) = 100
        <div>
            specificity of this element (0,1,0,1) = 101
        </div>
        <div class="smaller">
            specificity of this element (0,1,1,1) = 111
        </div>
        <div class="smaller" style="font-size: 0.5em;">
            specificity of this element (1,1,1,1) = 1111
        </div>
        <p>
            specificity of this element (0,0,0,0) = 0
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) is a very good post explaining how specificity works.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is because your global `*` style. Your nested `div` has no `class` or `id`, and the browser tries to find the first applicable style element, and it is the `*`.

Comment: It doesn't use the first applicable one, it uses the most specific one. In this case there is only one that matches at all.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, you are right, I used the wrong word.